# SOLR/C# - Is it possible to query one SOLR index, and attach a document from another index?

Tags: c#, .net, solr, e-commerce

Let's say i have index one with product data:

```
productid
productprice
productcategory
productname
```

And index two with customer prices:

```
customerid
customerprice
productid
```

How would i go about making a query to index one, where (if customer is logged in), theres a field retrieving the matching value (customerid, productid) from index two?

And is there a need for index two, or is there a more efficient way to store/retrieve customer specific prices?

Thanks in advance

*Update*

There is approximately 7.000 customers and 2 million prices, if you need a "scope" on performance.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want. Can you provide an example? Take a look at LINQ if you haven't - great query framework.

Comment: @Kokolo my bad, i might have forgotten to put in SOLR somewhere in my post :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all do something simple / working.

1) Solution 1 / SOLR index
Solr is not a DB, it's a search engine, but if your prices are very volatile (changes a lot...etc). Better to go for a Database implementation.

> There is approximately 7.000 customers and 2 million prices, if you need a "scope" on performance.
>   Solr is done to manage a lot of references. Don't be afraid of that, you need to build good indexes, the rest is managed by solr.

Even though, if your want to use solr, perform one index this this fields:

```
- productid 
- productprice 
- productcategory 
- productname 
- customerid
- customerprice
```

2) I will suggest you to use Redis DB,  your use case is not really a search engine. In redis you will store like this

```
product:{productid} => {productprice, productcategory, productname}
product:{productid}:customer:{custumerid} => {customerprice}
```

Redis is blazing fast, is scallable and is loaded in memory!

Comment: Hmm Redis looks interesting. The reason ive been looking at SOLR is because of their built-in facet functionality, which suits me perfectly because the site is more or less built as alot of filtering pages. The only problem i have is the customer specific prices, which i have to find a way to store in SOLR. Do you know if Redis has some kind of built-in / easy to build facetting functionality?

Comment: Im gonna stick with SOLR i think and performance test your first example. I feel like SOLR is better than a database in this scenario, because of the other search functionality i need, from SOLR. Thanks.

Comment: solr is a good option. I have over 10 years of production xp with it, this is a robust tool.